# Creating calculated items in powerpivot

Tags: powerpivot

I am trying to create a new row of data like the following:

Line item.                Actuals
Total compensation        200
Net revenue               400
Net rev per total comp.   2

I used to be able to do a calculated item to do this in old pivot table but how do I accomplish in powerpivot? It needs to be a row calc not a column

Comment: Sarah, I am not sure what source data you use and what is the desired outcome. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sounds like you want a calculated measure: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg399077.aspx This is really basic functionality in Power Pivot.

Comment: No it's not a measure. It is taking 2 rows and dividing them by each other. It needs to be in the row, not the column

Comment: Ok, so you want a calculated column then? You will need to post more about your data model for us to help you. Maybe add a picture of a table and point out where the numbers come from that you are trying to divide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a ssas cube then it is possible using the calculated member option where you can drag and drop line items (members) and divide which is pretty easy

Just connect to SSAS and Query --> Design in the upper menu you can find a calculator, clicking that you can achieve.

can you just elaborate on database used and excel version